# Отсутствие методов стандартной библиотеки Котлина в проекте на Android Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, library, android-jetpack-compose

При создании нового проекта средствами Андроид Студии выбрал шаблон `Empty Compose Activity`. Проблема в том, что некоторые методы стандартной библиотеки отсутствуют, либо их **не определяет** Андроид Студия. Однако проект собирается *успешно* (и даже отображается превью).

[image: Проблема]

Пробовал делать `Invalidate Caches / Restart`, удалял папку `.idea` и `.gradle`, перезагружал компьютер, в общем всё что можно, кроме переустановки студии.

Вот версия Андроид Студии:

[image: Версия Андроид Студии]

Файлы сборки Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.5'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pryanik.mastermind"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0'
    // Tests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

Comment: Пробовал в Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1, никаких проблем нет, никакой красный цвет ни для `min`, ни для `toCharArray`.